# I'm trying to add roles in discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def verify(ctx, account_name):
    member = ctx.message.author
    driver.get("https://www.realmeye.com/")
    found = ''
    search = driver.find_element_by_id("e")
    search.send_keys(account_name)
    search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(1)
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'h1')
    for e in elements:
        found = e.text
    if found == account_name:
        await member.add_roles(768895440312991807, member, 781458580712456192, reason = None )
    else:
        await ctx.send("Error: Account not found")
```

All I keep getting is the same error message. What I'm trying to do is check if a username is taken on a webpage and if it is add a role. But all i get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bailey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/Bailey/Documents/Discord server/AcidicBot/AcidicBot.py", line 114, in verify
    await member.add_roles(768895440312991807, member, 781458580712456192, reason = None )
  File "C:\Users\Bailey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 664, in add_roles        
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bailey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Bailey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bailey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 1):

`add_roles` takes `discord.Role`s, not the `id`s of the roles.

I'm not sure what the second `id` and the `member` are doing in there as parameters, those don't belong there. You're calling `add_roles` *on* the `Member` that you want to add the roles to, so there's no need to add the member itself as a parameter.

I'll also assume the second `id` is the `guild`, which is also unnecessary because a `Member` is already linked to a certain `guild` so it already knows which guild to add the roles in.

```
if found == account_name:
    role = member.guild.get_role(768895440312991807)
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

PS `ctx.message.author` is obsolete (`ctx.author` works too & is shorter), and `reason=None` can just be left out as well.